# Unable to create and Store all values in a variable as Complete Array in JQuery using each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I have huge amount of records in a html table and I want to get  values of all those records in jQuery Loop basis on their corresponding ID. But I am able to get only some records's value e.g. 1465 out of 2300 in my citationsId Array type variable  there. Can anybody  please let me know that how can I get the complete values of each and every ID.

I am unable to Create and Store array type of variable through each loop in which I can store huge elements.

**CODE :**

```
var citationsId = [];var i = 1;                                                             
    $( ".case" ).each(function() {              
        if($("#Zip_"+i).attr('checked'))
        {                                                    
            citationsId[i] = $( "#CID_PRIME_"+i ).val();                        
        }                                             
        i++;                            
    });
```

Comment: Side note: Never use `.attr('checked')` with jQuery >= 1.6 to check the state of a checkbox, as it will tell you the html attribute's value (i.e. INITIAL state of the checkbox). Use `.prop('checked')` instead.

Comment: can you show your HTML?